# How to calculate total hours using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add the total hours where flag =1. Here is how my data look like in the table.  The hours are 30 minutes interval

```
ID        FullDateTime              Flag
22      2015-02-26 05:30:00.000      1     
44      2015-02-26 05:00:00.000      1
25      2015-02-26 04:30:00.000      0
23      2015-02-26 04:00:00.000      1
74      2015-02-26 03:30:00.000      1
36      2015-02-26 03:00:00.000      0
```

here is what i tried but not working:

```
 select DATEDIFF(minute, sum(FullDatetime), sum(FullDatetime)) / 60.0 as hours                 
    from myTable
       where flag = 1
```

I am expecting the results to be 2 hours.

Comment: what's not working? You're subtracting the same two things, whatever a `sum(FullDateTime)` is supposed to be. How do you "add" two dates together?

Comment: Please post (add to your question)  the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: What's the number you're expecting? If it's 2 hours then maybe `select count(*) * 0.5 from your_table where flag = 1` could be what you want?

Comment: i am expecting 2 hours.

Comment: Cast the timestamps to epoch.

Comment: @jpw - if you just add up a half hour for each flag=1 row then you only get one hour.  This is almost certainly a window function to see the diff betwen the current row and the previous row with a flag=1

Comment: @Randy Last time I did math 4*0.5 = 2. But maybe I totally misunderstood what the question asks - if I did I'll delete my answer and stand corrected.

Comment: @jpw - yes you are correct, i am questioning the clarity of the question and the limited data example.  the problem here begins with the data model

Answer (score 1):

If the total number of hours is just a function of the number of half hour periods flagged as 1 then a simple count(*) of the rows matching flag 1 multiplied by 0.5 (for the half hour) should do it:

```
select count(*) * 0.5 from myTable where flag = 1
```

Comment: @moe Oh, I can't see how that would be possible. With your sample data count should return 4 and the result would be 4*.05=2.0.